# How to get matching string and correponding first line of a paragraphi from a text file . File contains multiple paragraph

Tags: shell, perl

I am having below data in a text file

```
[abcd]
sgsgdh
shshdhd
shdhdhd

[defg]
sgshdhd
shshdjd
shshdhd
shehddkd
shejdjd

[jkhl]
sgshdjdj
shejdjr
shshdhd
sgehdjd
shehdjjd
```

output

```
[abcd] : shshdhd

[defg] : shshdhd

[defg] : shshdhd
```

and so on

Comment: What does "matching string" mean? Is that something about the `[section]` lines?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {RS = ""; FS = "\n"; OFS = " : "} {print $1, $2}' file
```

```
[abcd] : sgsgdh
[defg] : sgshdhd
[jkhl] : sgshdjdj
```

If you want the blank lines in the output, add `ORS = "\n\n"` to the BEGIN block